# How to handle relative paths of xsds while publishing wsdl in spring web services?

Tags: web-services, soap, xsd, wsdl

I have a Soap web services exposed through Springs...
I need to expose the WSDL for the same. My Bean definition to expose the WSDL is as shown below.

```
<bean id="schemaCollection" class="org.springframework.xml.xsd.commons.CommonsXsdSchemaCollection">
<description>
This bean wrap the messages.xsd (which imports types.xsd), and inlines them as a one.
</description>
<property name="xsds">
<list>
<value>/WEB-INF/classes/schema/HL7V3/NE2008/multicacheschemas/PRPA_IN201301UV02.xsd</value>
<value>/WEB-INF/classes/schema/HL7V3/NE2008/multicacheschemas/PRPA_IN201302UV02.xsd</value>
<value>/WEB-INF/classes/schema/HL7V3/NE2008/multicacheschemas/PRPA_IN201304UV02.xsd</value>
<value>/WEB-INF/classes/schema/HL7V3/NE2008/multicacheschemas/MCCI_IN000002UV01.xsd</value>
<value>/WEB-INF/classes/schema/HL7V3/NE2008/multicacheschemas/PRPA_IN201309UV02.xsd</value>
<value>/WEB-INF/classes/schema/HL7V3/NE2008/multicacheschemas/PRPA_IN201310UV02.xsd</value>
</list>
</property>
<property name="inline" value="true"/>
</bean>

<bean id="pixManager" class="org.springframework.ws.wsdl.wsdl11.DefaultWsdl11Definition">
<property name="schemaCollection" ref ="schemaCollection"/>
<property name="portTypeName" value="PIXManager_PortType"/>
<property name="locationUri" value="/services/pixManager/"/>
</bean>
```

The problem I am facing here is I have child XSDs that are referred from these XSDs as shown below which is not getting resolved.

```
<xs:include schemaLocation="../coreschemas/infrastructureRoot.xsd"/>
```

I am getting the following error..

```
Caused by: org.springframework.xml.xsd.commons.CommonsXsdSchemaException: Schema [ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/classes/schema/HL7V3/NE2008/multicaches
chemas/PRPA_IN201301UV02.xsd]] could not be loaded; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The resource path [/../coreschemas/infrastructu
reRoot.xsd] has been normalized to [null] which is not valid
```

Where [/../coreschemas/infrastructu
    reRoot.xsd] is the relative path of the child XSDs.

Answer (score 1):

You need extract only schemas required for your interaction(s), so the folder structure will be like this:

```
../coreschemas
../schemas
```

and then "flatten" an interaction schema and related schemas into one which you may then embed into your WSDL.